spl token unable to send
import React, { FC, useCallback } from "react";
import { WalletNotConnectedError } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { PublicKey, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createTransferInstruction } from "@solana/spl-token";
export const SendSPLTokenToAddress: FC = () => {
const { connection } = useConnection();
const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
const fromTokenAccount = new PublicKey("EcC5EofwYE8Rc2Xx9ireNMRCRTRVF8JvpQZBtQNxbA4f");
const toTokenAccount = new PublicKey("6XTdUWzp6YBy35p2HJT3As1cH2GTeBBK31AJoYiNFxHJ");
const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createTransferInstruction(
    fromTokenAccount,  // Source token account
    toTokenAccount,    // Destination token account
    publicKey,         // Owner of the source token account
    1,                 // Amount to transfer (in smallest unit of the token, usually lamports for SOL)
    [],                // No additional signers required
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID   // Token program ID
  )
);

const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);

await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "processed");

}, [publicKey, sendTransaction, connection, fromTokenAccount, toTokenAccount]);
return (

Send 1 token to a specified address!

);
};

This is the token mint you provided EcC5EofwYE8Rc2Xx9ireNMRCRTRVF8JvpQZBtQNxbA4f.
You can use the getAssociatedTokenAddressSync which derives the associated token address for you
const mint = new PublicKey("EcC5EofwYE8Rc2Xx9ireNMRCRTRVF8JvpQZBtQNxbA4f")

const from = new PublicKey("EcC5EofwYE8Rc2Xx9ireNMRCRTRVF8JvpQZBtQNxbA4f")
const to = new PublicKey("EcC5EofwYE8Rc2Xx9ireNMRCRTRVF8JvpQZBtQNxbA4f")

const fromTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        from
    );

const toTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
        mint,
        to
    );

const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createTransferInstruction(
    fromTokenAccount,  // Source token account
    toTokenAccount,    // Destination token account
    publicKey,         // Owner of the source token account
    1,                 // Amount to transfer (in smallest unit of the token, usually lamports for SOL)
    [],                // No additional signers required
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID   // Token program ID
  )
);

